# TableLayoutPanel - Add scrollbar by row count

Tags: .net, scrollbar, rows, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel inside a userconrol. I want to add a vertical scroll bar to the panel conditionally - only when there are more than 5 rows. The table layout panel needs to display 5 rows only, no matter what is the size of the user control. The other rows, if there are, will be in the table layout panel, but will be shown only when scrolling down.

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks.